# Showing facets for variant products

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, facet

we have facets on search page, all of them are taken from BP index, how can I add a new facet filter with params from variant index? when I run search query it build facets only with BP fields.

Comment: Does your solr index only Base Products or variants as well? Can you see variants on PLP page?

Comment: Hello @RicardoMachado yes we have variant index, but on search result page we use search template based on product index. So on PLP we have only BPs

Comment: To add a new facet all you have to do is open one indexed property and flagged it as facet=true. Then all you have to do is create an indexed property and create a valueProvider that will build the facet values the way you want. 

If you have variant products being indexed, you should have access to them on value provider.